# Error while using local.py (settings) in Django 1.8.2

Tags: python, django, python-3.4

I wanted to implement settings as explained by "Two Scoops of Django". I referred their book and also their [github sample code](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/tree/develop/project_name).

I am getting the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

The problem is solved when I add the following code to `__init__.py` in settings folder:

```
from .local import *
```

Kindly explain what is happening as there is no code in `__init__.py` in all the examples on internet.

**I am using** Django 1.8.2 on Python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

When you include `__init__.py` in the folder, that folder is marked as a package called `settings`, from which you can import modules like your `local` module

This is a fairly standard thing in Python, even if not every Django programmer uses `settings` as a package

From Python docs:

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In
>   the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can
>   also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__`
>   variable, described later.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

> my question is do I need to write from .local import * in **init**.py
>   for the package to work?

Check your `manage.py` file it should load the `settings.local`, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "{{ project_name }}.settings.local")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Also check the actual value of `SECRET_KEY` in the local module see if it is empty or not (if e.g. you use some variable interpolation)

Comment: I understand the use of `__init__.py` but my question is do I need to write `from .local import *` in `__init__.py` for the package to work?

Comment: No you're not require to have code in `__init__`, maybe you are loading the wrong module from `manage.py`? You should load your `settings.local` module in there, also check `SECRET_KEY` is in there and if you use variable interpolation make sure it works and returns a non empty string

Comment: I have the `SECRET_KEY` set in `base.py`. I am importing it to `local.py` using `from my_project.settings.base import *`. I hope this is fine.

Comment: Try read the value of settings.local.SECRET_KEY? is it empty?

Comment: Do you have circular dependencies? e.g. if base reads local and local reads base you might create strange things, in `local.py` I would just put `from .base import *` without the absolute path that you're using

Comment: Same error after using `from .base import *`. I am using Pycharm. Any Pycharm specific settings I need to review? I know it's weird but left with no more place to look.

Comment: Assuming your PyCharm setup uses the correct versions and environments I don't see a problem, although maybe the way your project is laid out is missing something, maybe you should create a minimal git repo with the code that reproduces this. I'll be happy to have a look. Also you might find that if you start a project over and lay it out carefully, sometimes the issues disappear :)

Comment: After changing the "Run/Debug Configuration" in Pycharm the error disappeared. Pycharm's "Environment Variables" setting kept overriding my manage.py `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` values. Thank you @bakkal for your time.